# PRTime to datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am writing a script that is retrieving information from file *places.sqlite* (history) and realized that it stores the time in the PRTime format. Is there a method available in Python which could convert this date time or do I have to make it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PRTime is the number of microseconds since 1970-01-01 (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/PRTime), so just do this to get UTC time:

```
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=pr_time)
```

For example,

```
print datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=time.time()*1000*1000)
```

Output:

```
2010-03-25 13:30:02.243000
```

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"Page not found"*

Comment: PRTime [is supposedly](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/forensics/sqlite/places.html) a 64-bit integer. Signed? Unsigned?

Comment: Is the epoch for PRTime in Firefox actually the same as the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)? It seems to be more than two months off. Example: This [Blender question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269746) from yesterday, visited today gets a visited PRTime of 1652059358936318 in the Firefox table. Unix time 1652059358 is some time May this year (2022-05-09T01:22:38Z+0. (`date +"%s"` right now returns 1658340534 on my system and `date --date='@1658340534'` returns `Mi 20. Jul 20:08:54 CEST 2022` (yes, for unknown reasons, in German.).

Comment: OK, the question is not about Firefox, but search engines may still lead here. And PRTime could still have a different epoch.

Comment: Here is a source for the epoch: [NSPR Reference, Chapter 14 Date and Time](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/reference/html/prtime.html#21166)

Comment: It is on the order of 6.2 million seconds off (about 73 days).

Comment: PR = [Portable Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Portable_Runtime) (*NS* in NSPR is for *Netscape*). The [time part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Portable_Runtime#Time): *""Calendar times are 64-bit signed numbers with units of microseconds. The epoch for calendar times is midnight, January 1, 1970, Greenwich Mean Time. Negative times extend to times before 1970, and positive numbers forward. Use of 64 bits allows a representation of times approximately in the range of −30000 to the year 30000."*

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built-in method, but it does seem quite trivial to implement:

```
>>> t = 1221842272303080
>>> t /= 1e6
>>> t
1221842272.30308
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 19, 17, 37, 52, 303080)
```

The result is local time. For [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) you could do:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(t)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2008, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=19, tm_hour=16, tm_min=37, tm_sec=52, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=263, tm_isdst=0)
```

That's py3k output, and it might differ slightly in Python 2.x.

Comment: Thanks just making sure i'm not re inventing the wheel