# What date format is this?

Tags: datetime, format

I exported my Firefox bookmarks, and the 'dateAdded' fields look like this:

```
1260492675000000
1260492675000000
1266542833000000
```

They're too big to be a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), and I can't make sense of them. What are they? (I want to convert it into something usable/readable.)

Comment: I am voting to close this as a duplicate of *[PRTime to datetime in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515782)* (despite the less general title). Both answers here are 100% link-only answers (without even a definition of what it is) and the links are all (effectively) broken (now redirect to a porn site). [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515782/prtime-to-datetime-in-python/2515860#2515860) to that question has: ***"PRTime is the number of microseconds since 1970-01-01"***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [PRTime](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/nspr/reference/prtime.html).

> This type is a 64-bit integer representing the number of microseconds since the NSPR epoch, midnight (00:00:00) 1 January 1970 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). A time after the epoch has a positive value, and a time before the epoch has a negative value.

Answer (score 3):

PRTime as described on this [page](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/nspr/reference/prtime.html).

You can extract the time using the f3e tool if you can find a link to it.